# If a sequence is bounded, are its subsequences bounded as well?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Lets say our infinite sequence is $A(n)$ and we have two subsequences of $A(n)$:

1. $A(2n)$
2. $A(2n-1)$

If $A(n)$ is a bounded sequences, does this imply the two subsequences above are also bounded?

Would the same apply vice-versa, where if we know that those two subsequences are bounded, THEN the sequence $A(n)$ is also bounded?

A formal proof to answer these questions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you provide the formal proofs?

Comment: I believe the answers for both are TRUE, but I struggle to prove them formally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose that $(A_n)$ is bounded. Then there is $c \ge 0$ such that

$|A_n| \le c$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Hence

$|A_{2n}| \le c$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

and

$|A_{2n-1}| \le c$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

This shows that $(A_{2n})$ and $(A_{2n-1})$ are bounded.

2. Now suppose that $(A_{2n})$ and $(A_{2n-1})$ are bounded. Then there are $c_1, c_2 \ge 0$ such that

$|A_{2n}| \le c_1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

and

$|A_{2n-1}| \le c_2$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Let $c:=\max\{c_1,c_2\}$. Then we have

$|A_n| \le c$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Therefore $(A_n)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{ A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence i.e. $\exists k,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, m < A_n < k$. Consider the subsequence $\{ A_{2n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Since $T \subseteq S$, every element of $T$ is also in $S$. Therefore, we can pick $k$ and $m$ to be $\dots$